# The closure of neighborhoods are also interior in what kind of metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of an open set $O$ is that any $x \in O$ has an open neighborhood with $N \subset O$. I am wondering in what kind of metric space is it true that there is a closure of such a neighborhood with $\overline{N} \subset O$.

I think the answer is that the metric space is complete (intuitively meaning that it has no "holes", so the closure is just including the boundary of the neighborhood) but I'm not sure about it, nor do I know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in any metric space. To see this, note that we may take $N$ to be a ball of radius $r$ for some $r$. Then every point in the complement of $O$ is a distance of at least $r$ from the center of $N$. If we let $B$ be the open ball with the same center but radius $r/2$, then the closure of $B$ consists of points that are at most $r/2$ away from the center and hence all such points are contained in $O$.

Comment: Oh, right. I just had a conceptual misunderstanding of a neighborhood in my head. Anyhow, is there a particular reason then that we choose neighborhoods to be open rather than closed?

Comment: @Soke for one, in my language neighborhoods are always open. Second, in topological spaces that are not metrizable we may not be able to find a neighborhood whose closure is contained in the open set.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, there is such an $N$ for every metric space.

Let $x_0\in O$ ($O$ is open in some metric space $A$). Then there is a ball $B(x_0,r_0)\subseteq O$.

Now if the metric is $d$, and $\iota:A\to A\times A$ is the function defined by $\iota (a)=(x_0,a)$, then $d\circ \iota :A\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (because both maps are continuous).

Set $M\subseteq A\times A$ where $M=(d\circ \iota)^{-1}([0,r_0/2])$. Then this set (which is really $\{x\in A|d(x_0,x)\leq r_0/2)\}$) is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, so it is closed. Also, $M\subseteq B(x_0,r_0)$

Define $N=B(x_0, r_0/2)$

Now notice that $N \subseteq M$, so $\overline{N}\subseteq M \subset B(x_0,r_0)$.